# First time using methods (java) and nothing is being returned to the console, where am I going wrong?

Tags: java, methods

I'm still learning the basics of coding in Java and have moved onto using methods which has thrown me. **My issue is nothing is being returned to the console and I have no idea why**. Here's my code:

```
public class MethodsPractice {

public int returnInteger (int num1, int num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}

public String[] upperCaseString(String[] strings){
    String[] upperStrings = new String[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
        upperStrings[i] = strings[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    return upperStrings;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MethodsPractice myMethods = new MethodsPractice();

    int result = myMethods.returnInteger (10,20);
    String[] names = {"Bob", "Alex", "Luke"};
    String[] newNames = myMethods.upperCaseString(names);

   }

}
```

Comment: To show something in the console is actually an instruction (`System.out.Println` or something like that) . You have no such instructions.

Comment: perhaps `System.out.println()` will help you ?

Comment: @Pac0 am I wrong in thinking that 'return' should return what I specify in the console?

Comment: @MikeFoski yes. Depending on your system and how you are calling your java program, it *might* show the return valule at the end of the program. But that's not actually your program doing it, only the things wrapped around (your operating system / shell / java launcher). Also, **your `main` method doesn't return anything** . Maybe this is what you are confused about. The values returned by any other function / method in your program are not the value returned by the program, which is the one returned by `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you just aren't putting anything to console. Your code creates a new object, does some math, then creates an array of strings, but it never does anything with those newly created objects, for ex: If you wanted to print the result of the math function you need to use:
`System.out.println(result);`

Java (mostly)does not print anything to console you don't tell it to.
System.out is the stream where you can print to console.
Of course, println is not the only function :) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was my understanding that putting 'return' would show what I was wanting in the console?

Comment: No, return in java means you want to return an object to the class/function that called it. So if I return a string, the other class can have the string object and use it. Here is the doc link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Answer (score 0):

`upperCaseString` just returns the a new array, which your `main` method saves to the `newNames` variable, and then does nothing with it. If you want to print it, you would have to do so explicitly, e.g.:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newNames));
```

Answer (score 0):

To see content in the console, you need to call the methods from `System.out` like

- `print()` : show content
- `println()` : show content and go to next line

To easily print arrays, there is tips like :

```
String[] newNames = myMethods.upperCaseString(names);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newNames));
```

---

The classic way to print array will be with for (or foreach loop)

```
for(int i = 0; i<newNames.length ; i++) // for loop
    System.out.print(newNames[i] + ", ");

 for(String str : newNames) // foreach loop
    System.out.print(str + ", ");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add an Console Output with:

```
System.out.print(); //without new line
```

or

```
System.out:println(); //starts a new line after output
```

For example:

```
public class MethodsPractice {

public int returnInteger (int num1, int num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}

public String[] upperCaseString(String[] strings){
    String[] upperStrings = new String[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
        upperStrings[i] = strings[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    return upperStrings;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MethodsPractice myMethods = new MethodsPractice();

    int result = myMethods.returnInteger (10,20);
    String[] names = {"Bob", "Alex", "Luke"};
    String[] newNames = myMethods.upperCaseString(names);
    System.out.print(name[0]);
    System.out.println(name[1]);
    System.out.print(name[2])
   }

}
```

In the Consol will output:

BobAlex

Luke

Comment: PS: When you type sysout and press then STRG+SPACE it will autogenerate System.out.println()